# Comparing strings, containing space with == in PHP

Tags: php, string-comparison

I am curious why this is happening in PHP:

```
'78' == ' 78' // true
'78' == '78 ' // false
```

I know that it's much better to use `strcmp` or the least `===`. I also know that when you compare numerical strings with `==` they are casted to numbers if possible. I also can accept that the leading space is ignored, so `(int)' 78'` is 78, and the answer is true in the first case, but I'm really confused why it's false in the second.

I thought that `'78'` is casted to `78` and `'78 '` is casted to `78`, too, so they are the same and the answer is true, but obviously, that's not the case.

Any help will be appreciated! Thank you very much in advance! :)

Comment: Here http://php.net/manual/fr/language.operators.comparison.php see the answer from arnaud at arnapou dot net. It's quite great

Comment: Thank you very much @Hearner, but I already read it before posting the question here. :) I was just wondering why `' 78'` is considered "numerical string" and the space is ignored, but in `'78 '` it is taken into consideration.

Comment: do a `var_dump();` and/or `print_r();` on both and see what shows up. That might explain it in its own right.

Comment: I have already faced this issue and I red this article. This doesn't give any answer but it confirmed the problem. I can't provide any answer though but I hope someone will. I wanna satisfy my curiosity

Comment: I var_dumped everything possible, but it didn't give me anything useful.

Comment: @Fred-ii- `var_dump` can't help here because PHP is converting it internally before the comparison. I asked some internals people who hang out in chat and they said it's not possible to see that from this end.

Comment: @Machavity Thanks, noted ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It all seems to go back to [this `is_numeric_string_ex` C function](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_operators.c#L2737).

To start at [the implementation of `==`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_operators.c#L1766):

```
ZEND_API int ZEND_FASTCALL compare_function(zval *result, zval *op1, zval *op2) {
    ...
    switch (TYPE_PAIR(Z_TYPE_P(op1), Z_TYPE_P(op2))) {
        ...
        case TYPE_PAIR(IS_STRING, IS_STRING):
            ...
            ZVAL_LONG(result, zendi_smart_strcmp(op1, op2));
```

If both operands are a string, it ends up calling [`zendi_smart_strcmp`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_operators.c#L2627)...

```
ZEND_API zend_long ZEND_FASTCALL zendi_smart_strcmp(zval *s1, zval *s2) {
    ...
    if ((ret1 = is_numeric_string_ex(Z_STRVAL_P(s1), Z_STRLEN_P(s1), &lval1, &dval1, 0, &oflow1)) &&
        (ret2 = is_numeric_string_ex(Z_STRVAL_P(s2), Z_STRLEN_P(s2), &lval2, &dval2, 0, &oflow2))) ...
```

Which calls `is_numeric_string_ex`...

```
/* Skip any whitespace
 * This is much faster than the isspace() function */
while (*str == ' ' || *str == '\t' || *str == '\n' || *str == '\r' || *str == '\v' || *str == '\f') {
    str++;
    length--;
}
ptr = str;
```

Which has explicit code to skip whitespace at the beginning, **but not at the end.**

Comment: This definitely deserves a [**good-answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/24/good-answer) badge. (Maybe submit it as manual page edit ? And add like a little gray "note:" box)

Comment: Thank you very much! This is just what I was looking for!

Comment: But if you try to compare `'78' == ' 78'` and `'78' == '78 '` like `78 == ' 78'` and `78 == '78 '` the return will be `true` in both cases. Why? Both continue being `string | integer`.

Comment: @Thiago That can be answered both from [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) and the source code: it's always using numeric comparison if any operand is a number. But if both are strings, then it depends on `is_numeric_string_ex` whether it will be treated as number or not, and this function returns something different for `'78 '` and `' 78'`.

Comment: When you compare string with integer, the string is casted to integer. You can try var_dump on `(int)' 78'` and  `(int)'78 '` - they both return the integer `78`, which is why the return will be true in both cases.

Answer (score -1):

The space on the end of '78 ' causes PHP to treat the variable as a string. you can use trim() to strip the spaces.

Comment: Thanks! I know about `trim()` and I will never use the above code, I was just searching for explanation and logic why it behaves this way. For me `' 78'` and `'78 '` are equally "stringish". Even more, if you cast both of them to integers, the answer will be 78 in both cases.

Comment: While you've nailed the problem and how to solve it, this doesn't explain the WHY part like the OP was asking.