# Why does PHP 8 treat 42 == " 42" as true?

Tags: php, php-8

PHP 8 has been released. It has made changes to the behaviour of the equality operator. According to [the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration80.incompatible.php), this is how it behaves now:

> Non-strict comparisons between numbers and non-numeric strings now work by casting the number to string and comparing the strings.

However, this expression evaluates to true both in PHP 8 and in earlier versions of PHP:

```
42 == " 42" // true
```

This doesn't make sense to me. According to the documentation, the number should be cast to a string, `"42"`, which surely is not equal to the string `" 42"`, right?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32310733/comparing-strings-containing-space-with-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Short answer:

In PHP 8 and in PHP 7, `42 == " 42"` is true, and in both PHP 7 and PHP 8, `"42" == " 42"` is true.

## Long answer:

I think you have a misconception of how the equality operator `==` works in PHP. Both in PHP 8 and in earlier versions of PHP, the equality operator treats strings that look numeric differently from other strings:

```
<?php
// the == operator does type juggling and also handles numerical strings differently:
var_export("42" == "42"); // true
var_export(42 == "42"); // true
var_export("42" == " 42"); // true
var_export("42" == "42 "); // false in PHP 7 and true in PHP 8
var_export("42" == "042"); // true
var_export("10" == "1e1"); // true
var_export("abc" == " abc"); // false
var_export("42" == "abc 42"); // false

echo "\n";

// the === operator does not do type juggling and does not handle numerical strings differently:
var_export("42" === "42"); // true
var_export(42 === "42"); // false
var_export("42" === " 42"); // false
var_export("42" === "42 "); // false
var_export("42" === "042"); // false
var_export("10" === "1e1"); // false
var_export("abc" === " abc"); // false
var_export("42" === "abc 42"); // false

echo "\n";
```

Even in PHP 8, the `==` operator both does type juggling and it handles numeric strings differently. That principle hasn't changed. What has changed in PHP 8 is:

- The equality operator `==` behaves differently in PHP 8 than in PHP 7 for comparisons between numbers and non-numeric strings
- What strings are considered numeric strings is different in PHP 8

Regarding the latter point, read this:

> Numeric string handling has been altered [in PHP 8] to be more intuitive and less error-prone. Trailing whitespace is now allowed in numeric strings for consistency with how leading whitespace is treated. This mostly affects:
>
> - The `is_numeric()` function
> - String-to-string comparisons
> - Type declarations
> - Increment and decrement operations

Answer (score 1):

The documentation you quote is actually correct, but could possibly be made clearer:

> Non-strict comparisons between numbers and **non-numeric strings** now work by casting the number to string and comparing the strings.

I've bolded the key phrase, which is "non-numeric strings".

Within various parts of PHP, there is the concept of a "numeric string" as a kind of pseudo-type: any string that *looks like* a number may be treated as one by parts of the language. This is to aid in PHP's primary use case of taking data from a web request (which will always be strings) and using it in operations (which might want to treat it as numbers).

One of the places this comes into play is the `==` operator, which tries to be "smart" about what you're trying to compare.

If PHP decides that both sides of the `==` operator are either numbers *or* numeric strings, it will perform the comparison by casting them both to integer (or float, if appropriate) and seeing if they have the same *numeric* value. The definition of a "numeric string" is quite broad, and allows leading spaces; as of PHP 8, it now also allows trailing spaces, for consistency.

So in your example, `" 42"` is a "numeric string", `42` is an actual number, so the comparison performed is `(int)" 42" === 42`

The change described in your quote is for the case where one side is an actual number (an integer or float) and the other side is a *non-numeric* string, that is one which PHP has decided "doesn't look like a number". In older versions of PHP, this would *also* cast to int, so `"hello" == 0` would evaluate `(int)"hello" === 0`, which is `true`. In PHP 8, *this* case casts to string instead, so `"hello" == 0` would evaluate `"hello" === (string)0`, which is `false`.