# PHP 8.0 changes how loose comparison works

Tags: php, php-8, loose-typing

Lets have a simple PHP script

```
<?php
var_dump("php" == 0);
```

According to official documentation (https://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php)
, this shoud evaulate into `true`

**BUT**
It does, for PHP <=7.4, but no for PHP 8.0

In current version of PHP 8 (8.0.0 - 8.0.2) it evaulates to `false`.

[image: Same script ran in different PHP docker images]

Are there any un-documented changes to this functionality or is this a bug? Or am I missing something?

Thank you

Comment: take a look to first article https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration80.incompatible.php

Comment: @SimoneRossaini I see, thank you. But should not this be also insluded in that link to official documentation (given that 8.0 is released) about type comparisions? Should I notify somebody or create pull request somewhere?

Comment: As you can see [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) your example exists

Comment: Yes, I did also linked this page in my question. But if you have a look at this exact example ("php" == 0), this page still tells, that it should equal true, which is not true for php 8

Comment: see my answer you saw wrong

Comment: no, "0" is not 0

Comment: What makes you think that the migration documentation is not part of the official documentation?

Comment: @NicoHaase should not "latest" documentation reflect "latest" state of software? e.g. If i need to know how particullar functionality works, do I need to go through all migration docs from the beginning to reconstruct current state?

Comment: Fair point. If you think that this needs more details, feel free to open a new bug ticket or attach your thoughts to https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=80502

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65040819/why-does-php-8-treat-42-42-as-true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP Documentation maintainer here, PHP 8 did change the semantics and this is shown in the migration guide. However other parts of the documentations are still lagging behind as we don't have the manpower/time for editing and documenting all the changes related to PHP 8.

So this is not a bug and more a fact that the current type juggling page is out of date in regards to PHP 8.0.

It is possible to contribute to the docs via a Pull Request to the [GitHub](https://github.com/php/doc-en) repository.

Comment: Thanks, this is answer I have been waiting for. Is there any way to help you out? e.x. submit pull request somewhere in docs. source code? Does something like this exist?

Comment: You're in luck we recently finished the migration from SVN to git, so the source code is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/php/doc-en) and the is an [internal issue tracker](https://github.com/php/php-tasks/issues/26) for the changes which need to be made (at least some of them)

Answer (score 5):

When PHP 8 got released, they also put a [release announcement](https://www.php.net/releases/8.0/en.php) on the website. This is part of one of the new major changes, the [saner string to number comparison](https://www.php.net/releases/8.0/en.php#saner-string-to-number-comparisons).

To quote:

> When comparing to a numeric string, PHP 8 uses a number comparison. Otherwise, it converts the number to a string and uses a string comparison.

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is documented in [Backward incompatible changes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration80.incompatible.php).

> String to Number Comparison
>
> Non-strict comparisons between numbers and non-numeric strings now
> work by casting the number to string and comparing the strings.
> Comparisons between numbers and numeric strings continue to work as
> before. Notably, this means that 0 == "not-a-number" is considered
> false now.