# PHP8 compare 0 with an empty string, what is the logic behind that

Tags: php, string-comparison, php-8

in PHP 8 why comparing 0 with an empty string, surprised me.

I can't understand the logic.

```
$a = 0;
$b = "";
echo ($a == false)  ? "yes a is False<br>" : "no<br>"; 
echo ($b == false)  ? "yes b is False<br>" : "no<br>"; 
echo ($a == $b) ? "yes a equals False and b equals to False" : "no, False is not equal to False!!!, there is a problem";
```

the output is `"no, False is not equal to False!!!, there is a problem"`

in the above code, I expected to give `yes a equals False and b equals False` but PHP surprised me.

can you help me to understand why the output is `no`?

`if(false == false)` it should return true and it works fine.

but,

`if("" == 0)` it should return true too, but it will return false, even `""` and `0` are false. **I want to know why???**

I want the logic behind this.

I use PHP 8.0.2

Comment: It's down to https://wiki.php.net/rfc/string_to_number_comparison.

Comment: See here https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration80.incompatible.php#migration80.incompatible.core.string-number-comparision Just documentation not updated.

Comment: As said in another [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66373499/11924322), this section of the documentation is out of date.

And as said by others this is due to the change how strings and numbers are compared as of PHP 8.

Comment: @Girgias, please read the question more carefully, `if("" == 0) it should return true too, but it will return false, even "" and 0 are false. I want to know why???` this is my question,  WHY?

Comment: I asked what is the logic behind that, and nobody answered, somebody, closed my question, but this link is not my answer, it's just documentation, it's not the reason, please open my question I want to add a bounty to it. thanks

Comment: The reason is that when a string is compared to a number (int or float) the string, prior to PHP 8.0, was *always* casted to the corresponding type, i.e. `"" == 0` was identical to `(int) "" == 0` which gives you `0 == 0` => `true`.

This is also the reason why prior to PHP 8.0 `"foo" == 0` was returning `true`

Answer (score 2):

There is an incompatibility in PHP 8. You can find it here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration80.incompatible.php

I recommend you cast your values before comparing

```
if (boolval($a) == boolval($b)) {
   // do stuff 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that happen because PHP8.

I try this code

```
 $a = 0;
 $b = "";
 $result = ($a == $b) ? "yes a equals False and b equals to False" : "no, False is not equal to False!!!, there is a problem";
 echo($result);
```

In PHP5 and PHP7 its return "yes a equals False and b equals to False" but in PHP8 its return "no, False is not equal to False!!!, there is a problem"

you can try its in [PHP online Sandbox](https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/)